# Google rejected publication the Chrome extension saying “Your Product violates the Privacy Policy & Secure Transmission section of the policy”

Tags: chrome-web-store

We have been trying to publish the new version of the extension which is already in Chrome Web Store, but Google rejected it sending the following email:

**Your item did not comply with the following section of our Program Policies:
"User Data Privacy"
The Privacy Policy & Secure Transmission section requires that:
If your product handles personal or sensitive user data (including personally identifiable information, financial and payment information, health information, authentication information, website content and resources, form data, web browsing activity, user-provided content and personal communications), then your product must:
- Post a privacy policy.
- Handle the user data securely, including transmitting it via modern cryptography.

To comply with this policy:
Provide a working link to your privacy policy in the appropriate field in the Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard.
The link must lead to a privacy policy that is owned by you.
The privacy policy must also accurately and fully disclose all the details pertaining to how your product collects, uses and shares user data, including the types of parties with whom the data is shared.**

There is the working Privacy Policy link in Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard that contains detailed information about which data we collect, how we do that and use this information; how this data transmitted and secured. We have also described the usage of permissions in Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard, but Google still declines our submission. We have been trying to directly contact Chrome Web Store team for more details, but ,unfortunately, there is no response from them and they are continuously sending the email above without additional clarifications... Did anyone experience the same problem? How were you manage to resolve it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a software development question but a [customer service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions) question.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same issue. My guess is that they're trying to have everyone comply with [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) &/or [CCPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Consumer_Privacy_Act) to be safe.

I will take a look at [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/privacy-policy#for-california-user)'s terms to see what a company that constantly updates their [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grammarly-for-chrome/kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen) does.

Chrome's [User Data FAQ](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/user_data)'s are also a great resource.

In my case, my extension is a free (not for profit) extension that does not really handle or store user information, nor does it track data. So I may try doing [what others have done](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/word-counter-plus/fpjegfbcdijjfkceenlfoehpcakfgldj) and just spell that out in the description.

Hope this helps!